# HTML custom form in wordpress submission

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms, submit

I have a custom HTML form for wordpress application:

0

Brief Description of Result in multiple lines

Fill out the form to get a free consultation.

Country
        
    
    
        
        
            Idea & Positioning
        
    
    Submit

```
function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var totPoint = document.querySelector('#totalPoints').textContent;
    var name = document.querySelector("#name").value;
    var email = document.querySelector("#email").value;
    var pNo = document.querySelector("#ph-no").value;
    var country = document.querySelector("#country").value;
    var company = document.querySelector("#company").value; // Fixed typo here
    var help = document.querySelector("#help").value;

    console.log({
        totalPoints: totPoint,
        Name: name,
        Email: email,
        Phone_No: pNo,
        Country: country,
        Company: company,
        Help: help
    });
}
```

I want to handle the submission in wordpress to send email to user. This is for a blogging website.

I have searched for different methods but couldn't find any that use only js and no other plugins or themes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.